# Getting solid green image with Gstreamer, VP8, and RTP

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, vp8

I don't understand why I'm getting a green image. I'd appreciate any insights.

Producer:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v videotestsrc ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001
```

Consumer:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=9001 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2990747501, clock-base=(uint)275641083, seqnum-base=(uint)34810" ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

[image: Green Box]

This is using the gstreamer-sdk-2013.6-universal.pkg package published from Gstreamer on OS X Mavericks.

REF: http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/stream-webm-video-over-rtp-with-gstreamer/

REF: http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/vp8-video-streaming-over-rtp-using-the-rtpbin-plugin-of-gstreamer/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it and it works on my machine (Arch linux).

Have you tried tweaking the ssrc and clock-base to make them equal ? Not sure if it can solve your problem because it works as-is on my machine.

Comment: Are you on a Mac (it works on my Linux system)? The sink doesn't take capabilities (does it?) and it doesn't seem to have parameters for these two.

Comment: I believe you might be right. I can encode, pay, depay, and decode, and see it properly from the same pipeline. It must be a capabilities thing: *gst-launch-0.10 -v videotestsrc ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink*

Comment: @Dustin Oprea No I'm not on a mac, I'm on Archlinux.
By the way, I'm not quite sure I understand your second comment : did you sovle your problem ? And if yes, what caused it ?

Comment: Not yet, but it works when I leave the difference in UDP capabilities out of the equation. Therefore, I think it could very well be one of the capabilities that you mentioned. How do you pass SSRC and clock-base to the *udpsrc* plugin?